# Amazon SES: How to send HTML mail to all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ses

I want to send all users (<200) on the rails application. The mail server is Amazon SES. If the lists were over 50, we have to divide email transactions.

So I coded like below:

```
class NewsMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def all_notify(news)
    @news = news
    @users = User.where(is_news: true)

    @users.each do |user|
      mail(
        subject: @news.title,
        to: user.email,
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Although email has been sent, but html was collapsed like this.
[image]

When I try to send to one user. It doesn't occur the problem. But when using `each` causes the problem...

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
  @users.each do |user|
    NewsMailer.all_notify(@news, user).deliver
  end
```

I could do it by writing `each` on the controller.